# List Columns and corresponding Table of all user tables in DB

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

Can someone help me list all **Columns** along with its **Table** of all User Tables in a database?
I do not want to list the system tables.

`SELECT name FROM syscolumns`

Gives me all column names but is there a way to exclude all the system tables from the result set?

Comment: As of SQL Server 2005, you should use the new system catalog views in the `sys` schema - not the "old" `sysobjects` views and the like. Those still work - for now. Try to use `sys.tables`, `sys.columns` and so forth from now on for new stuff you do

Comment: I see! This also gave me the desired result:

`select table_name, column_name from 
INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select b.name as tablename, a.name as columnname
from syscolumns a join sys.tables b on a.id = b.object_id
where b.type='U';
```

`Type U` = user-defined Tables!

System tables would be `Type = S` so with this query you avoid them!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
--  o.type,
--  o.type_desc,
    o.name AS object_name,
    c.name AS column_name
FROM sys.columns c

    INNER JOIN sys.objects o
        ON o.object_id = c.object_id
WHERE
    o.type = 'U'

ORDER BY
    o.name,
    c.name
```